# Multiply partially a Panda Matrix by another

Tags: pandas, matrix

I would like to create a new panda matrix from two panda matrix.

I don't know exactly how to describe my problem without an example.

So, my matrix A:

```
    1               2           3           4         5
1   0.821124    0.767681    0.639456    0.131096   0.398733
2   0.108253    0.865229    0.285755    0.409036   0.398622
3   0.529245    0.989824    0.283102    0.392597   0.983236
4   0.699661    0.828631    0.404465    0.027329   0.936447
5   0.983737    0.262978    0.387633    2.228383   0.677531
```

And my matrix B:

```
            A                       B
            a           b           a          b
A   a   0.090075    0.550466    0.748526    0.338671
    b   0.577898    0.005927    0.718440    0.482596
B   a   0.042174    0.332807    0.214504    0.781927
    b   0.819624    0.066917    0.372023    0.459321
```

I would like to get a matrix C:

```
            A                                B
            a                 b              a               b
            1        2        3       4      5       2       3       4
A   a   1   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
        2   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    b   3   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
        4   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
B   a   5   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
        2   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    b   3   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
        4   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

And fill in sort to get for each cell.

```
C((A,b,3)(A,a,1))= A((3)(1))*B((A,b)(A,a))
```

Here, (A,b,2) is the row and (A,a,1) is the column. E.g. :

```
C((A,b,3)(A,a,1)) = 0.529245 * 0.577898.
C((B,b,4)(A,a,2)) = 0.828631 * 0.819624
```

I succeed to build this C matrix with loops and C.loc from Panda. But it is very slow. My matrix A is around 2000 * 10 000 and my matrix B 4000*4000, and my matrix C is around 400 000 * 400 000 (with one more level if we compare to this example).

It looks like I multiply the A by B for each second level of C, but here the index of A and C don't always match.

How I can deal with that without lose my hair.
Thanks in advance.

My only way to optimize my calculus now is to divide my works by core with MPI. But it is still slow.

Comment: Could you share code on how to setup that NaN's filled `C`?

Comment: I created my index thanks to a query on a RDF database.
So it is hard to share a code. But I can easily get dict with the proper index for C and I make the matrix via this command:

       `import pandas as pd`
        `index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples({('A', '1'), ('A', '2'), ('B', '1'), ('B', '2')})`
        `pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=index)`